# How to re-assign objects in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

**[Current code]:**

```
a = table.a
b = table.b
c = table.c
```

**[Expected Output]**

```
all = [a, b, c]
for i in all:
 i = table.i
```

Comment: Yes. I think it is possible . but update the `all` list `["a", "b", "c"]`

Comment: Note that `i = table.i` is useless code inside a loop, you're only reassigning an iteration variable, not creating new variables that will live outside of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this piece of code is not inside a function (or, if it is inside a function but `a`, `b` and `c` are not needed anywhere else outside of that function) it can be done without using another container by updating the `locals` dict:

```
attributes = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for attr in attributes:
    locals()[attr] = getattr(table, attr)
```

For example:

```
table = type('table', (), {'a': 1})()

attributes = ['a']
for attr in attributes:
    locals()[attr] = getattr(table, attr)

print(a)
```

Outputs

```
1
```

Just be aware of the consequences: if there are another variables `a`, `b` and `c` (there shouldn't because these are bad variable names) in that scope they will be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is closer to what you intend, using a dict as a repository for the dynamic variables:

```
class Table(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
        self.b = None
        self.c = None
        self.d = None
        self.e = None

table = Table()
table.a = 1
table.b = 2
table.c = 3
table.d = 4
table.e = 5

# copy only this variables
some_vars = ['a', 'b', 'c']

# this line does the trick
my_vars = { var: getattr(table, var) for var in some_vars }
```

Now we've captured the object's attributes as key-value pairs in a dictionary:

```
my_vars['a']
=> 1
my_vars['b']
=> 2
my_vars['c']
=> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying `i` within `for i in all` will not change the elements of `all`, but you could instead iterate like this:

```
class Table(object):
  pass

table = Table()
table.a = 'AAA'
table.b = 'BBB'
table.c = 'CCC'

all = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for idx in range(len(all)):
    all[idx] = getattr(table, all[idx])

print(all)
```

Output:

```
['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']
```

Comment: ... but you've lost the name of the variables, it's just a list of values with no way to refer to them by a name.